# React KeyDown event handler in compnent - function error

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a web page with ReactJs and I am stuck with one issue. I am trying to handle enter key press in my page using keydown event. Following is piece of code:

```
class ManageUser extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      window.addEventListener("keydown", this.keyEventHandler, false);
    }
    keyEventHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {        
       if (event.keyCode === KEY_CODE.ENTER) {
          this.handlerUserEntry(); //Getting error here....
       }
    }
    handlerUserEntry() {
       console.log('handle user entry here');
    }
}
```

I am able to capture enter key event. But when I try to call `this.handlerUserEntry();` from `keyEventHandler` function I am getting following error:

> TypeError: this.handlerUserEntry is not a function

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You probably need to bind handlerUserEntry: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb/

Comment: Did you try to pass the event to your handleUserEntry function. Plus update it to be an arrow function, so it is bound to your Class component

Comment: I have tried this as well. This does not work. If I call this.handleUserEntry() from other functions its working fine. Issue is only when keydown event occurs.

Comment: not a solution but I think you are using a older version of managing events with a older react. i have used similar functionality but the code definitely does not look like this.

Answer (score 0):

As Florian suggested in their comment, any function references you pass need to be bound to your class, otherwise the `this` in `this.handlerUserEntry` will not point to the `ManageUser` class.

You can do this by adding a constructor with the rest of your code as-is:

```
class ManageUser extends React.Component {
    ManageUser(props) {
        this.handleUserEntry = this.handleUserEntry.bind(this);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I have tried this as well. This does not work. If I call this.handleUserEntry() from other functions its working fine. Issue is only when keydown event occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using componentDidMount() as its a [deprecated feature in React's current docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html).

I was able to get a working component with a little help on React Events [here](https://reactarmory.com/guides/learn-react-by-itself/inputs-and-events).

Below is my working component:

```
import React from 'react';

class ManageUser extends React.Component {

    handler(event) {
        alert(`
            key: ${event.key}
            keyCode: ${event.keyCode}
            altKey: ${event.altKey}
            ctrlKey: ${event.ctrlKey}
            metaKey: ${event.metaKey}
            shiftKey: ${event.shiftKey}
        `)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                <input
                    placeholder='Hit a key...'
                    onKeyDown={this.handler}
                    onKeyPress={this.handler}
                    onKeyUp={this.handler}
                    />
            </div>
        )
        
    }
}

export default ManageUser
```

Comment: componentDidUpdate() is not deprecated. Please check the documentation. I would like to handle keydown event on a window, not from a specific control.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using custom keydown handler, i started using 'react-keydown' npm package and issue is resolved.